# How to add training data to the model after initial training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to add data for my scikit-learn model after it has already been trained. For example, I have the data that I used in the beginning (there are about 250 of them). After that, I need to train this model one more time by calling the function, and so on. The only thing that came to my mind was to add new values ​​to the existing data array every time and train the model again, but this is very resource-intensive and takes more time.

Is there another way to train the machine learning model?

```
model = LinearRegression().fit(test, result)
reg.predict(task)
### and here I want to add some data, for example one or two examples like:
model.addFit(one_test, one_result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer in your case (using the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` model) is **no, it is not possible to add one or two more examples and train without adding this to the original training set and fitting it all at the same time.** [Under the hood](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), the model is simply using Ordinary Least Squares (described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)) which requires the complete matrix of training data on which to fit your model. However, this algorithm is very fast and in the case of ~ hundreds of training examples, it would be very quick to re-calculate the parameters of the model with each new couple examples.